# When I switch fragment the data is reverted back to its original state in firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When I'm on fragment A (item from bottomNavigation), I update a field in firestore with coroutines, however when I switch fragment the data is reverted back to it's original form. The context is a bottomNavigation.

```
   suspend fun update(id:String){
    fbase.collection("collectionName")
        .document(id)
        .update("voted", "true")

        .addOnSuccessListener {}
        .await()
   }
```

The update occurs on fragment A  with liveData therefore I don't think it's an issue with coroutines, but with activity and fragment.

Comment: I believe what may be causing your issue is that your coroutine is being cancelled when you navigate away from `FragmentA`. Can you post the code that starts the coroutine?

Comment: Is the update() function triggered every time you open fragmentA?